# Is that async function call in initState() method always be called after build() method in Flutter?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

I have a test code bellow:

```
class SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  Future<void> dummy() async {
      print('Async function1');
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => print('Async function2'));
      print('Async function3');
      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => print('Async function4'));
      print('Async function5');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState 1');
    super.initState();
    print('initState 2');
    Future.sync(() {
      print('Future sync');

    });
    print('initState 3');
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      print('Future value');
    });
    print('initState 4');
    dummy();
    print('initState 5');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('1'),
      ),
      body: Text('2'),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

```
I/flutter (16218): initState 1
I/flutter (16218): initState 2
I/flutter (16218): Future sync
I/flutter (16218): initState 3
I/flutter (16218): initState 4
I/flutter (16218): Async function1
I/flutter (16218): Async function3
I/flutter (16218): initState 5
I/flutter (16218): build
I/flutter (16218): Future value
I/flutter (16218): Async function2
I/flutter (16218): Async function4
I/flutter (16218): Async function5
```

I tested it 100 times and the order alway be the same with every build. Because of async programming, I wonder that "Is this order always keep every run?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter or should I say Dart is single Threaded programming and it works in the event loop mechanism.
So every time dart sees async function without await keyword it just goes and puts it in an event loop and after all current process finishes it comes back and revives that async function. If there is await keyword as you have before in `print('Async function5');` it checks for event loop and revives previous stacks of events in sequence they were added with respect to delay.

[Check for more details](https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-ccbca2543ae9)

There you can find all the details of how it works. also, don't forget to check out this videos

[Flutter dev video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY) 
[and how Isolates introduced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8jGSkACneE)

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you for your suggest.